# How do I create virtualhosts on CentOS 64bit server?

Tags: centos, virtualhost

I have CentOS 64bit with Apache, where is the virtual hosts located so I can create a few vhosts, to setup multiple domains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a file called `httpd.conf` in `/etc/httpd/conf` directory.  Uncomment the following:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin root@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog logs/localhost-error_log
    CustomLog logs/localhost-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

`NameVirtualHost` enables Name Virtual Hosting.  The section for `ServerAdmin` is a contact email address.  `DocumentRoot` is where your www files are located for this vhost.  `ServerName` is useful for subdomains and such, but I generally use it to name the domain/subdomain/site.  `ErrorLog` and `CustomLog` directives are usually per vhost, so that they aren't all logged into the same error/custom log, however, these are going to be where your error and access logs will be stored and written to - make sure the directory/file can be written by the apache user.

Answer (score 0):

Using Apache on CentOS is pretty much like using Apache on any other platform.  The configuration files are in `/etc/httpd/`, and the Apache documentation is [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/).  If you have specific questions about something, let us know.